# ¿Cuál es la manera adecuada de puntuar una oración interrogativa que ha sido interrumpida y luego reanudada?

Tags: traducción, sintaxis, puntuación, palabras-interrogativas

Considerando la siguiente construcción en inglés:

> What if Alexandra is actually a... Wait for it... criminal?

Me gustaría saber cuál sería la forma adecuada de llevarla al español conservando su sentido interrogativo directo. Se me han ocurrido varias soluciones, pero no sé si están del todo correctas.

1° alternativa:

> ¿Y si Alexandra es realmente una...? Espera... ¿Delincuente?

2° alternativa:

> *¿Y si Alexandra es realmente una...? Espera... ¿...delincuente?

¿Habría alguna manera de hacer que la interrupción (por el mismo locutor que hace la pregunta) quede adentro de una sola oración interrogativa?

Answer (score 3):

> What if Alexandra is actually a... Wait for it... criminal?

Pueden haber otras elecciones de estilo, pero —ciñíéndonos al ejemplo directo— me parece que la traducción puede hacerse conteniendo toda la frase en una sola interrogación; para reflejar la duda, la tensión de la suspicacia que se se despierta a mitad de camino en el desarrollo del pensamiento, y la hipótesis inquietante en la que la sospecha deriva:

> - *¿Qué si en realidad Alejandra es..., espera un momento..., una delincuente?*

Answer (score 2):

Al igual que en la versión en inglés, no veo razón para añadir un signo de cierre de interrogación antes de que acabe la pregunta. La oración "espera..." es un inciso, y como tal debe escribirse separada por [comas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/coma), [rayas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/raya) o [paréntesis](https://www.rae.es/dpd/par%C3%A9ntesis). Según el DPD, la elección depende del "nivel de aislamiento" del inciso con respecto al texto principal. Si la pregunta es parte de un diálogo, la raya puede confundirse con una aclaración del narrador que no forma parte del diálogo. Yo utilizaría por tanto comas:

- ¿Y si Alexandra es realmente una..., espera..., delincuente?

Este uso de comas después de puntos suspensivos se parece al ejemplo que da el DPD del uso de [puntos suspensivos](https://www.rae.es/dpd/puntos%20suspensivos) para indicar una pausa transitoria que expresa, entre otros, suspense:

> Quería preguntarte... No sé..., bueno..., que si quieres ir conmigo a la fiesta

Comment: Saludos. En tal caso, ¿no importa el hecho de que el inciso esté entre los signos de interrogación a pesar de él estar expresando una orden en vez de una duda? Además, según tengo entendido, al eliminar los puntos suspensivos la oración debe de seguir teniendo sentido; sin embargo, en este caso quedaría "¿Y si Alexandra es realmente una, espera, delincuente?", ¿sigue siendo aceptable así?

Comment: @Xggggg Este es un caso muy especial, y la RAE no parece haberlo tratado directamente, por lo que hay algo de libertad. Pero los incisos que no son parte de una pregunta normalmente se escriben dentro de ella, sin cerrar y abrir la pregunta de nuevo. Ejemplos de la RAE: "[¿Cuántos países integran la ONU (Organización de las Naciones Unidas)?](https://www.rae.es/dpd/par%C3%A9ntesis)", "[¡Esto que has hecho —se dirigía hacia mí con el gesto descompuesto— es una auténtica locura!](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=hMzWCSVPOzcUczkT)".